# IntelliJ - Include module but exclude from build

Tags: android, build, intellij-idea

I am trying the following:

Include an Android Module in my project.
Excluding it from actual build (if you e.g. press rebuild project).

Background: The Android module compilation takes 20 sec I don't want to wait, because I am only doing desktop tests at the moment. But I can't remove the Android Module completely from the project, would loose refactoring features (would not run later after e.g. I renamed classes in library project).

Any ideas how I can tell him to e.g. not DEX the Android (overwrite the build in Android ANT script with empty one is one way which comes to mind). Any tips are welcome...

Chris

Comment: Why do you use Rebuild? `Build` | `Make` is incremental and will not build unchanged files in this module every time.

Comment: I know, normally I simply press RUN and he builds the required files (fast). But some times IntelliJ screws up and I have to make sure he builds all clean, he does not detect broken code in some files otherwise.

Comment: You should report these cases at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA so that IDEA doesn't break and you don't have to rebuild.

Comment: Why don't create another run configuration and remove build android from it?